# Amount is not populating correctly

Tags: sql-server

I have this query which I wrote to get the opening balance and balance amount but it is not calculating the `CrAmount`. I'm not sure if I can provide table structure and data as that's too large and complex to put here so if anyone could spot out the issue.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
    [Master].[TransactionCode], [Master].[TransactionDate], SUM(DrAmount) [DrAmount], SUM(CrAmount) [CrAmount]
    FROM 
    [FICO].[tbl_TransactionDetail] [Detail], [FICO].[tbl_TransactionMaster] [Master]

    --WHERE [VoucherDate] BETWEEN CAST('Dec  01 2017 12:00AM' AS DATE) AND CAST('Dec 30 2017 12:00AM' AS DATE)
    WHERE 
    [Master].[ID] = [Detail].[TransactionCode] 

    GROUP BY [Detail].[ID], [Master].[TransactionCode], [Master].[TransactionDate]
)
SELECT TransactionCode, [TransactionDate], D.DrAmount, D.CrAmount, D.Amount, D.Amount-ISNULL(D.DrAmount,D.CrAmount) [Opening]
FROM(
    SELECT *,
            SUM(ISNULL(DrAmount, 0)+ISNULL(CrAmount, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY TransactionCode 
                     ) as Amount
    FROM CTE
    )D

WHERE D.[TransactionDate] BETWEEN CAST('Mar 26 2018 12:00AM' AS DATE) AND CAST('Mar 30 2018 12:00AM' AS DATE)
```

Output is this. Here if the DrAmount is given it will subtract it from Amount and show Opening Balance. Amount is being calculated with respect to previous entries in the database.

```
TransactionCode                                    TransactionDate         DrAmount                                CrAmount                                Amount                                  Opening
-------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
CPV--43---18                                       2018-03-26 00:00:00.000 25000.0000000                           0.0000000                               98666164.0000000                        98641164.0000000
CPV--43---18                                       2018-03-26 00:00:00.000 0.0000000                               28700.0000000                           98666164.0000000                        98666164.0000000
CPV--43---18                                       2018-03-26 00:00:00.000 1500.0000000                            0.0000000                               98666164.0000000                        98664664.0000000
CPV--43---18                                       2018-03-26 00:00:00.000 2200.0000000                            0.0000000                               98666164.0000000                        98663964.0000000
CPV--44---18                                       2018-03-27 00:00:00.000 2300.0000000                            0.0000000                               98670764.0000000                        98668464.0000000
CPV--44---18                                       2018-03-27 00:00:00.000 0.0000000                               2300.0000000                            98670764.0000000                        98670764.0000000
```

Comment: You mention it does not calculate CrAmount, but in the CrAmount column in the output there's non-0 values. Can you elaborate further on what exactly you are missing? Are there NULL values involved? Could you provide some of the input data that leads to this output so we can try and figure out what's happening?

Comment: I don't know how you think anyone can possibly suggest anything if you don't give sample data, and why you think the result you are getting is wrong.

Comment: You have only two tables, how complicated can it be? And you don't have to provide volumes of data, just enough to demonstrate the problem. You also should start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should handle it like this:

```
DR = case when SUM(DR-CR) >=0 then SUM(DR-CR) else 0 end
CR = case when SUM(CR-DR) >=0 then SUM(CR-DR) else 0 end
```

Here's how to apply this:

```
--put in your dates here
declare @start date = '20180301'
    , @end date = '20180331' 

select transactionid
     ,DR = case when SUM(DR-CR) >=0 then SUM(DR-CR) else 0 end
     ,CR = case when SUM(CR-DR) >=0 then SUM(CR-DR) else 0 end 
from detail d
     join header h on d.id=h.id
where trandate <= @start
group by transactionID

union all

select transactionid, DR,CR
from detail
    join header h on d.id=h.id
where transdate between @start and @end
```

Comment: My guess is that your grouping should not be transaction code but some kind of acct code